# Is it a bad idea to use ASHX for an entire website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I made multiple website in the past using HTML or Perl. I am now looking to use ASP.Net since it allow me to use a language that I am more comfortable with (C#).

I made some experiments with the aspx pages and it seems like they always add viewstates and add an extra request to the server from my current understandings.

I am just looking to have something that will have the ability to use POST/GET data like any ordinary webpage + the ability to use c#.

Currently, I am thinking about making the entire website using the ashx format since it seems like the format that is the closest to fullfill these needs. This would imply that I would probably need to create a custom template manager to print mix of static html content and generated content.

Does it sound like a bad approach? I don't need a system (aspx) that will add weight to my pages and slow down the process if I already handle everything using POST/GET requests no?

Comment: ASP.NET does _not_ always add ViewState - it can be disabled. It is also not intrinsically a bad thing. It's only bad when it is abused. Also, ASP.NET MVC does not use ViewState at all, and may be more of what you're looking for if you're coming from a Perl background.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking at webforms. This is pretty much a legacy technology now, look at MVC/WebAPI which are far superior.

Comment: There are a lot of options here.  You can use Asp.Net WebAPI to create a rest based server and then use plain HTML with JavaScript ajax calls.  You can also use Asp.Net MVC, which doesn't use a view state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASHXs are basically handler pages.  In a webforms-laden site, ASHXs were often used for one-off JS calls, image handler, or to basically fill that niche where you wouldn't normally create a full-on ASPX.

From what you describe, your aim is to create lightweight pages where you have a bit more control, and it sounds like what you need is [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Further, depending on what you're actually doing, you should look at ASP.NET MVC for web pages.  If you're simply creating an API, then have a look at [ASP.NET WebAPIs](http://www.asp.net/web-api) instead.  Both paradigms are very similar to each other, take care of a lot of management for you and are not considered legacy (as of the time of writing anyway)

To answer your question more directly - it may not be entirely bad to use ASHX for a few endpoints that you need to compliment something else, but it can certainly become bad as the scope of the application increases over time and you add more and more pages.  You end up with a monolithic 'page' structure repeating itself over a project, which may not be conducive to maintenance; whereas with the MVC approach you will at least have the structure in place for some quality control and separation. ASP.NET MVC already gives you the separation, templates and control over your pages, so it is a good fit.

tl;dr - yes, it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I made some experiments with the aspx pages and it seems like they always add viewstates and add an extra request to the server from my current understandings.

The first thing I did in the days of the older ASP.NET was to turn that rubbish off.

> I am just looking to have something that will have the ability to use POST/GET data like any ordinary webpage + the ability to use c#.

I'd recommend ASP.NET MVC.

> Currently, I am thinking about making the entire website using the ashx format since it seems like the format that is the closest to fullfill these needs. This would imply that I would probably need to create a custom template manager to print mix of static html content and generated content.

There are times when either ashx work well. There are also times when implementations of IHttpHandler work very well, and there can be cases (especially when the output is not HTML) where that is both simpler to code and more efficient to run.

Otherwise while there are some issues with ASP.NET MVC (the very fact that it just considers all matters related to the streaming of the entity to the client as "the view" gets in the way of tweaking the streaming of the entity to the client), it nicely separates out the C# part and the HTML part. Indeed, when I was doing ASP.NET "wrong" in not using ViewState among other ways in which I went against the by-the-book advice as to how one was "meant to" do ASP.NET, I was doing what ASP.NET MVC with Razor now supports directly.

> I don't need a system (aspx) that will add weight to my pages and slow down the process if I already handle everything using POST/GET requests no?

No, and you don't **need** what ASP.NET MVC gives you either, but it does a reasonably good job of staying out of ones way. Indeed, I find that it's ASHX that falls between two stools for me; in cases where it makes sense I often find it handier just to implement IHttpHandler, but YMMV on that point.

Answer (score 0):

- Viewstate

  - in `WebForms` this is one way it handles persistence
  - it can be disabled entirely or selectively (e.g. persistence for *some* controls, not *all* in a `Page`).
- ASP.Net is

  - WebForms
  - WebPages (lightweight, Razor syntax - *typically* associated with the use of `WebMatrix`)
  - MVC
  - WebApi

So you have options.

> I am just looking to have something that will have the ability to use POST/GET data like any ordinary webpage + the ability to use c#.

If you're the "bare metal" type, then `WebPages` and `MVC` will be appealing. Not to say that you can't do same in `WebForms` - its still POST/GET at the end of the day (just somewhat abstracted for ease of use).

The other answers handle the choice between `Generic Handler` (ashx) and `WebApi`.

Hth.